# Facing issues with sdkmanager while setting up Flutter development environment on Arch Linux

Tags: android, flutter, archlinux

I'm currently trying to set up a Flutter development environment on Arch Linux, but I'm facing some issues.

Environment:

- OS: Arch Linux
- Shell: fish
- Java: OpenJDK 8, OpenJDK 11 (both tried but encountered the same error)
- Flutter: 3.7.12

Issues:

- When running the sdkmanager command as a regular user, I encounter the following error: "Error: Main class java.se.ee not found or could not be loaded."
- On the other hand, when executing sdkmanager with sudo, the error does not occur.
- The flutter doctor command also shows some Android-related errors.

Attempted solutions:

- Set ANDROID_HOME and granted permissions to /opt/android-sdk.
- Changed the permissions of /opt/android-sdk by running chown -R username:usergroup.
- Used the archlinux-java command to switch Java versions on Arch Linux.

Despite these steps, the issue persists. If anyone knows a solution, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Self resolved.
I unset the following environment variable and it worked.

`JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'`

It seems that the user still had the settings that were set during the trial and error and that was the cause of the problem.